# How automatically to zoom on current location and always to be focused on it in google maps api v3(android)?

Tags: android, google-maps

How to realize automaticly update of current location in the android? It is necessary that location was always in focus and focus was updated in case of location change.

I used an official google example(with button):

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

    /**
     * Flag indicating whether a requested permission has been denied after returning in
     * {@link #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])}.
     */
    private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

    /**
     * Request code for location permission request.
     *
     * @see #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])
     */
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        enableMyLocation();

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    /**
     * Enables the My Location layer if the fine location permission has been granted.
     */
    private void enableMyLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission to access the location is missing.
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        } else if (mMap != null) {
            // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }

        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
            mPermissionDenied = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        if (mPermissionDenied) {
            // Permission was not granted, display error dialog.
            showMissingPermissionError();
            mPermissionDenied = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays a dialog with error message explaining that the location permission is missing.
     */
    private void showMissingPermissionError() {
        PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
                .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
```

P.S. Maybe it makes look a like in api v2? Someone have tutorial for this?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @MayurPatel posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this.getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
```

Call `buildGoogleApiClient()` in your `onMapReady()` callback

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

                    },
                    100);
            return;
        }
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            //place marker at current position
            //mGoogleMap.clear();
            latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            currLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5);
            mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
        }

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); //3 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //1/10 meter


}
```

For this to work you should get key to enable LocationsAPI from [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com)

Comment: No, app is working, but doesn't do anything. Do you have email or something?

Comment: Check this source
https://github.com/HTTPERROR404/Android-Samples/tree/master/MyApplication
That is my repository and uses above code. Do use your own API key